# Bug in siunitx when used with tex4ht and mathjax?

Tags: siunitx, tex4ht, mathjax

Compiling the file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    The speed is $v = 3$ \si[per-mode=symbol]{\meter\per\second}.
\end{document}
```

using `make4ht test.tex "xhtml,mathjax"` puts a part of the `siunitx` source code in the output `test.html`

```
<body>
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>The speed is \(v = 3\) \(\relax \exp_args:NV \__siunitx_print_math_auxiii:n \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl \).
</p>
</body>
```

Any idea how to fix this so that the produced `html` file renders the units correctly?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled: Reading it backwards do you ask for a bug fix, of a workaround for a reported bug? Thanks

Comment: In response to the comment by @MS-SPO, to reduce confusion, I am posting the temporary solution as a comment:

[I submitted a bug report](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/530#issue-971022798) to the `siunitx` git, but in the meantime, while the developers figure out the best way to rectify the situation, this document complies perfectly with the older version `\usepackage{siunitx-v2}` instead of `\usepackage{siunitx}`.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the question, then? Sounds more like a solution.

Comment: I posted the question first, thinking I was doing something wrong. Then, I found out that it works with older version of the package, so I reported a bug. I can delete the question, but I thought it may be helpful to others that might encounter the same problem. Questions on this site seem to come up in search results more frequently than GitHub bug reports.

Comment: @Rushi Please don';t force-load the v2 file like that: the intended fallback usage is `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`.

Comment: @Rushi, Ok, I see. With the rules of this place in mind then it would be better to use the Q&A-format. It's easy to overlook: when you click on "Ask Question" in the lower left of the form you can select "Answer your own question". This allows e.g. to give some more background on the question first. The test.tex you mention might be useful to display, for example. // However, I'm not sure if and how your current question can be converted into a Q&A-style. I  can't see this option when editing your post, but may be you can.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that the next time something like this comes up.

As for this question, I think @JosephWright's answer makes this discussion moot, so I will leave it as it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present you can use

```latex
\sisetup{mode = text}
```

which is what v2 does. I am considering a few better long-term approaches and will update in due course.